# Save NUMBER as TIMESTAMP in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, logging, slf4j, logback

Hi dear Java and Oracle folks.

I am using `DBAppender` apprender from Logback to Oracle. For Oracle, `DBAppender` comes with script for creating table. It logs Timestamps to `Number(20)`, because normally timespamps are 13 long digits(miliseconds) and Oracles digits accepts only 9 digits(up to seconds). So in SQL Developer on outup i see 13 long digits and it is very impractical. I do not have calculator in my head to translate digits to Date.

My question:
Is there other solution for storing timestamp in Oracle as Timestamp instead of `NUMBER`, so i can see it?

OR

Is there a way in SQL Developer to read this `NUMBER(20)` ad Date?

Thank you very much.

Petr

Comment: Just a word of advice: Go for a view which makes the number readable for you. Oracle (and SQL in general) has some odd quirks (some make sense, some don't) when it comes to date/time types. That's probably the main reason why logback decided to save the timestamp as a `NUMBER(20)`.

Comment: Never experienced "odd quirks" with Oracle date/time types. And I work with them for a long time. Anyway, use the builtin DATETIME datatype http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00203

Answer (score 0):

One solution you may find here, written by me:)

http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-963

Hope this will help to anyone struggling with the same isuue.

But if anyone finds other solution, please write it down.